# WearableListenerService - smartphone cannot find wear as a node?

Tags: java, android, smartphone, wear-os

I have my smartphone connected to a wear emulator and I use Android Studio.

The emulator and my phone app are both using `WearableListenerService` with an overridden `onMessageReceived()` and while the emulator is able to successfully send a message to my phone using `MessageApi`, the device cannot send one back - the no nodes are found at all despite the emulator finding my phone as a node. I originally used the `MessageEvent.getSourceNodeId()` method with the `MessageEvent` argument supplied to `onMessageReceived()` but that didn't work either.

My plan is to send a message to my phone with and have the phone relay a message back instantly after.

Is there something I need to do on the phone side of things in order to message my wear device? I have followed the instructions of many guides: both applicationIds are the same, the directories are the same, Manifests are fine, I used Generate Signed APK... still nothing!

Thanks.

Code used to send a message to phone:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SendToWear {

public static final String TAG = "DEMO_WEAR_LOG";

private static GoogleApiClient sClient = null;

public static int sendMessage(Context context, String path, String data){
    Log.d(TAG, "Path: " + path);
    ArrayList<String> nodes;
    int sent, connectCount = 0;

    if(context == null || path == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Context or Path is null.");
        return 0;
    }

    if(sClient == null) {
        sClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
    }
    sClient.connect();

    ConnectionResult connectionResult =
            sClient.blockingConnect(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to sClient.");
        return 0;
    } else Log.d(TAG, "sClient connected!");

    // no nodes, loop useless
    nodes = getNodes(sClient);
    if(nodes.size() == 0) return 0;

    for(int i = sent = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                sClient, nodes.get(i), path, data.getBytes()).await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // was not able to send message
        if(result.getStatus().isSuccess())
            ++sent;
    }

    sClient.disconnect();

    Log.d(TAG, "SENT: " + sent);

    return sent;

}

private static ArrayList<String> getNodes(GoogleApiClient client) {
    Log.d(TAG, "in getNodes");
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes =
            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if(nodes == null || !nodes.getStatus().isSuccess())
        return results;

    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
        results.add(node.getId());
    }

    return results;
}
}
```

Comment: Edited with code now.

Comment: Just to reiterate: this identical code works when the Wear sends a message to Device, but Device won't send one immediately back afterwards using the above code.

Comment: If you still cannot, Try Wear Samples available in Android SDK Folder.